# Changing text on first span with class `is-empty` on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Where I'm at

- Clicking on a `.player` on this grid of 50 hockey players grabs the name of that player
- It then opens a popup box where a user can add that player to their
  team by clicking a button `btn-add`. I'm then switching the text of the first empty span in a list, which displays the names of the players a person has selected, using `.eq()` and `.html()` based on their position — **`player--forward`**, **`player--defenseman`** or **`player--goalie`**

## Problem

When I click on the `btn-add` button, it changes the text of the first empty slot for all three positions' `spans`: **`player--forward`**, **`player--defenseman`** or **`player--goalie`** with the name of the player last clicked, instead of just that position.

### scripts.js

```
function countPlayers(){
    $(".player").click(function(){

        // Count number of players of each position that have been clicked
        var pickedF = $(".player--forward.is-selected").length;
        var pickedD = $(".player--defenseman.is-selected").length;
        var pickedG = $(".player--goalie.is-selected").length;

        console.log(pickedF, pickedD, pickedG);

        // Grab the name of the player last clicked
        playerName = $(this).find(".player__name").text();
        console.log(playerName);

        $(".btn--add").click(function(){
            if ($(".player").hasClass("player--forward")) {
                $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");
            }

            if ($(".player").hasClass("player--defenseman")) {
                $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");
            }

            if ($(".player").hasClass("player--goalie")) {
                $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

### index.html

```
<div class="popup clearfix">
    <div class="icon-container">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <img src="" alt="" class="popup__picture">

    <div class="popup__text">
        <p class="popup__position">tk-position</p>
        <p class="popup__name">tk-name</p>
        <p class="popup__years">tk-years</p>
        <p class="popup__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi ad dicta sunt unde, sed quae nihil inventore voluptates nulla voluptate laudantium nesciunt quo, aspernatur deleniti quod harum, nisi error doloribus.</p>
        <div class="popup__stats">
            <p>tk-stats</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn--add">Add to team</button>
            <button class="btn--remove">Remove from team</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


        <div class="info__group info--team">
            <img src="img/team-2.png" class="team">
            <p class="info__header">Make Your Own Team</p>
            <p>Select and share your dream team online by clicking on a player to see their stats, learn more about their impact on the Blues and why they were chosen for our Top 50 list.</p>
            <ul>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--forward is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a forward</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--forward is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a forward</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--defenseman is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a defenseman</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--defenseman is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a defenseman</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--defenseman is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a defenseman</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--goalie is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a goalie</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <div class="player player--elliott player--goalie" data-id="14">
        <div class="player__info animated">
            <p class="player__name">Brian Elliott</p>
            <p class="player__position ">Goalie</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="player player--sutter player--forward" data-id="15">
        <div class="player__info animated">
            <p class="player__name">Brian Sutter</p>
            <p class="player__position">Forward</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="player player--pronger player--defenseman" data-id="16">
        <div class="player__info animated">
            <p class="player__name">Chris Pronger</p>
            <p class="player__position">Defenseman</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `$(".btn--add").click(function(){` your if lines are checking if `$(".player")` has a class, that's not going to be specific to the current player that the user has clicked on, it's going to check if anything with the class `player` has one of those three classes (which it looks like they do) so all three if statements are always going to run.

If you store your current player in a variable when it's clicked, then you can target just that player later on in your button click function. Here's an example:

```
$(".player").click(function(){
    var player = $(this); // select current player div
    // Count number of players of each position that have been clicked
    var pickedF = $(".player--forward.is-selected").length;
    var pickedD = $(".player--defenseman.is-selected").length;
    var pickedG = $(".player--goalie.is-selected").length;

    console.log(pickedF, pickedD, pickedG);

    // Grab the name of the player last clicked
    playerName = player.find(".player__name").text();
    console.log(playerName);

    $(".btn--add").click(function(){
        if (player.hasClass("player--forward")) {
            $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
            $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");
        }

        if (player.hasClass("player--defenseman")) {
            $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
            $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");
        }

        if (player.hasClass("player--goalie")) {
            $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
            $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that jeff!

Comment: This is close, but not there yet.

Comment: @jeff carey I'm seeing some weird behavior when I click on a `player--forward` and then I click on a `player--defensemen` it changes the text of two empty slots

Comment: I added another edit which was not approved yet. before you add the $(".btn--add") click handler, unbind all the previous ones you added by writing $(".btn--add").unbind("click");

Comment: What does unbind do in this case?

Comment: @AndrewNguyen unbind is going to prevent you from having multiple events bound to your button click event, which is probably what was causing the weird behavior you saw earlier